# MongoMapper issue with stack level being too deep

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

Just want to start off by saying I did google this topic at length and was unable to find anything that applied to my own use case.

I have a simple little ad server. There is a model for `Ad`, and two embedded models called `Impression` and `Click` - like so:

```
class Ad

  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :image, String
  key :url, String

  has_many :clicks
  has_many :impressions

end

class Click

  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :ip, String
  timestamps!

end

class Impression

  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :ip, String
  timestamps!

end
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:194
```

Here is the area that this is happening in:

```
@ad.impressions << Impression.new({:ip => request.ip})
@ad.save
```

Now, I do not have any callbacks here in my models, which is the reason this error happens for a lot of people.

Anyone have any insights?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have hit on the answer. the `timestamps!` is what was causing this. The other examples I saw online had to do with callbacks and the way that ActiveSupport runs them. I just didn't realize that `timestamps!` counts as one.